# Parse: How can I update all rows with the same key value

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

How can I update all rows with the same key value in a Parse class?
As my code, I think Parse would cost a lot of my money if there are 100 objects per user.
Is there any other way to do that?

```
    let username = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
    let objectQuery = PFQuery(className: "FriendList")
    objectQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: username!)

    objectQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (friendList:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if let friendList = friendList as? [PFObject] {
            for myInfo in friendList {
                myInfo["contact"] = contact
                myInfo["portrait"] = PFFile(data: portraitNSData)
                myInfo["company"] = company
                myInfo["position"] = position
                myInfo.save()  // create a request?
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse has a functions to object see to save many objects (see documentation [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/saveAllInBackground:block:))

```
PFObject.saveAllInBackground(array, block: {
        (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            println("Error saving: \(error)")
        }
    })
```

Unfortunately the documentation is not update to Swift but you can see a list of the function in objective-c

> - saveAll:
> - saveAll:error:
> - saveAllInBackground:
> - saveAllInBackground:block:

Comment: @What_Ever Great news! Good luck with your app!

Answer (score 1):

Form array of needed objects and than just

```
PFObject.saveAllInBackground(objectsArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to create a CloudCode function. Then call that function from iOS. It's not difficult, see their documentation here: [Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#cloud-code)